# How to store the parts of the string in dictionary in java

Tags: java, string, dictionary

I want to store string split-ted into two parts into dictionary in 0th and 1st position.
Suppose value is frequency:50 then frequency will be in 0th place and 50 will be in 1st place in dictionary
following is the C# code for same

```
data_dictionary = data.Split(',')
  .ToDictionary(item => item.Split(':')[0], item => item.Split(':')[1]);
```

I want the solution for same in java,any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, without closures Java can't approach the elegance of your C# code. You *may* find something that uses anonymous classes to approximate this, but it will not be really worth it. So just write out a regular loop that `put`s stuff into a `HashMap<String, String>`. You can split the string the same way, using `String#split(regex)`.

Comment: I am not able to solve this question, just wanted to know can I make use of arraylist and add the content of the substrings into that arraylist or else can you please provide me any example since I am able to find difficult to understand it

Answer (score 0):

```
int delim = data.indexOf(':');

System.out.println( data.substring(0,delim) ); //frequency
System.out.println( data.substring(delim+1) );   //50
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted something a bit closure-esque then it would probably have a function signature like:

```
interface KeyPairFunctor<T, K, V> {
    Pair<K, V> getKeyValuePair(T item);
 }

public static <T, K, V> Map<K, V> toMap(Iterable<T> items, KeyPairFunctor<T, K, V> functor) {
    Map<K, V> m = new HashMap<K,V>();
    for (T item : items) {
        Pair<K, V> e = functor.getKeyValuePair(item);
        m.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
    }
    return m;
 }

public static void test() {
    toMap(Arrays.asList(new String[] { "A:B" }), new KeyPairFunctor<String, String, String>() {

        @Override
        public Pair<String, String> getKeyValuePair(String item) {
            String[] ss = item.split(":");
            return new Pair(ss[0], ss[1]);
        }});
}
```

Implementation of `Pair` is left as an exercise to the reader and I'm sure you can see how you can put your `,` split list in the first argument.